# Java try catch (InputMismatchException) unexpected loop

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

Im trying to catch an `InputMismatchException` it works at the first interraction , but when the `menu()` method is called again , it starts looping until it gets stuck in an error.

In the `try catch` my objective was to get an error message and after that start the `menu()` method again.

I have the following code:

```
public class Menu extends ProfilesManager {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void menu() {

        int number;
        System.out.println("** Welcome... **\n  ");
        System.out.println("* what you wanna do?:\n");
        System.out.println("(1) Login  \n(2) Register  \n(3) Find User  \n(4) Exit\n");
        System.out.print("-Answer?: ");

        try {
            number = sc.nextInt();            
            if (number == 1) {
                Login();
            } else if (number == 2) {
                Register(); 
            } else if (number == 3) {
                FindUser(); 
            } else if (number== 4) {
                Exit();
            }                                                    
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {   
            System.out.println("Error , only numbers!!");
            menu();           
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `menuPrinc();`? If you want to restart something, use an actual loop, not recursion

Comment: i think you just have to call `menu()` in the `catch` block

Comment: menuPrinc() is the menu() method , I forgot to correct it,sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because once you enter a wrong input. you are not clearing it and `Scanner` will keep on reading it and every time it will give you `InputMisMatchException`

You need to clear it in your catch block

```
}catch(InputMismatchException e){

    System.out.println("Error , only numbers!!");
    sc.nextLine();
    // Put 2 second delay
    try{
         Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    menu();

}
```

Comment: the only problem is that the errorr message can't be seen , it jumps straight without showing it .

Comment: Thats because error message and menu display are in quick succession.. to mitigate this issue you can put `Thread.sleep` just before `menu` call

Answer (score 1):

You have infinite recursion. You gotta move menu() out of the catch block if you want to call it again. Otherwise it's infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should write `sc = new Scanner(System.in);` after `System.out.println("Error , only numbers!!");`